# Django JSONField filter greater than an attribute value

Tags: python, json, django, django-models

I have the following Django model:

> class Student(models.Model):
>
> ```
> student_id = models.CharField(primary_key=True, max_length=10)
>
> student_info = JSONField()
> ```

My data looks like:

> {
>
> “student_id": “1",
>
> “student_info":{
>
> “student_name": “Parker",
>
> “age": "21",
>
> “num_classes": “5",
>
> “highest_score": “75",
>
> “credits_complete": “13”,
>
> “credits_remaining”:”20"
>
> }
>
> }

I want to select all students with credit complete greater than 13. I tried the following which returns me an empty Queryset:

> Student.objects.filter(student_info__credits_complete__gt='13’)

Any idea how to filter greater than or less than the attribute value in JSONField?

Thanks!

Comment: maybe store `credits_complete` as an integer and use an integer in the query?

Comment: No. student_info is a jsonb field in my Postgresql db. I am looking for filtering on JSONField.

Comment: I meant that store `credits_complete` in the json as an integer. Currently, its a string in there.

Comment: I changed it to an integer and it worked.